# Run a repeated test reporting as different tests

Tags: c++, cppunit

I'd like to unit test a function with a set of different inputs and expected outputs.

My function is irrelevant thus I'll instead use an example function which counts english words with the following candidate implementation :

```
int countEnglishWords( const std::string& text )
{
  return 5;
};
```

The following would be the set of test data. The end of the data is marked by an element with the word "END".

```
struct TestData {
  std::string text;
  int englishWords;
};

struct TestData data[] = // Mark end with "END"
{
  { "The car is very fast", 5 },
  { "El coche es muy rapido", 0 },
  { "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain", 9},
  { "XXXXX OOOOO TTTT", 0},
  { "Yes Si No No", 3},
  { "I have a cheerful live", 5},
  { "END", 0}
};
```

I could easily write 6 test cases and I would get the result I want. But this is not maintainable, since any further test added to the test cases would not be tested, it would require another test case to be written, which would be just boiler plate. Thus I've written a single test case which loops through all the test data like this :

```
#include <cppunit/ui/text/TestRunner.h>
#include <cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h>

class cppUnit_test: public CppUnit::TestFixture
{
private:
   CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE (cppUnit_test);
   CPPUNIT_TEST(myTest);
   CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

public:
   void myTest();
};

void cppUnit_test::myTest()
{
  TestData* p = data;
  while ( p->text != "END")
  {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Text=\"" << p->text << "\" Counted=" << 
       countEnglishWords(p->text) << " Expected=" << p->englishWords;
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE( ss.str().c_str(), 
                countEnglishWords(p->text) == p->englishWords );
    ++p;
  }
}

int main()
{
   CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION (cppUnit_test);
   CppUnit::Test *suite =
         CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest();
   CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;
   runner.addTest(suite);
   runner.run();
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the previous code runs through the 1st test fine and also detects the error in the 2nd test but after that it stops testing. And the report is :

> !!!FAILURES!!!
>   Test Results:
>   Run:  1   Failures: 1   Errors: 0

While the result I'd like to get is :

> !!!FAILURES!!!
>   Test Results:
>   Run:  6   Failures: 4   Errors: 0

Comment: Cppunit 1.14 provides support for this feature. There is CPPUNIT_TEST_PARAMETERIZED and the TestCaller now accepts any callable that can be converted to std::function<void()>. Both can be used to implement the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As I already mentioned in the comment cppunit 1.14.0 can support your use case.

I you want to reference an external array the quickest way is to use CPPUNIT_TEST_PARAMETERIZED. This macro expects two parameters: first similar to CPPUNIT_TEST a test method and then as a second parameter an iteratable.

Based on your code it would look like:

```
CPPUNIT_TEST_PARAMETERIZED(myTest, aData);
```

Now we need to adapt your myTest function a little bit.

```
void cppUnit_test::myTest(const TestData& data)
{
    std::stringstream ss; 
    ss << "Text=\"" << data.text << "\" Counted=" <<  
        countEnglishWords(data.text) << " Expected=" << data.englishWords;

    bool b = countEnglishWords(data.text) == data.englishWords;
    std::string a = ss.str();
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_MESSAGE( a,  
            b); 
}
```

Finally as the framework needs a way to report which test failed it expects that it can print the parameter that is passed to the test function. In this case the easiest way is to add a simple operator<< overload.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const TestData& data)
{
    strm << data.text;
    return strm;
}
```

If you combine these pieces you should quickly get a generic solution that will allow you to add as much data to your data array as you want without adapting the test code.

Answer (score -1):

```
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(TestSuite);
CPPUNIT_TEST_PARAMETERIZED(testMethod, {1, 2, 3, 4});
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

void testMethod(int /*val*/)
{
}
```